# Python iteration 'Nonetype' using 'in' statement

Tags: python, json, dataset, iteration, nonetype

Hi so I loaded a JSON file into a list using the following code:

```
import json    
postal_mtl = ['H9W','H4W','H9P','H3B','H3A','H2Z','H3H','H3G','H3X','H9J','H1B','H1G','H1H','H4X','H2Y','H9R','H3Z','H3Y']
data = []
with open('business.json',encoding="utf8") as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line))
```

Now I am trying to find the number of restaurants in montreal in this dataset (coming from Yelp). I tried the following code:

```
compteur3 = 0
for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i]['postal_code'][0:3] in postal_mtl and 'Restaurants' in data[i]['categories']:
        compteur3 += 1
print(compteur3)
```

But I am getting an error saying "argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable" I guess Python considers the date[i]['categories'] as a Nonetype ? Why is that ? If I enter the following I can see that it's clearly a string:

```
data[5]['categories']
'Shipping Centers, Couriers & Delivery Services, Local Services, Printing Services'
```

Now I just want to iterate over all the elements in my data list and find each line where we have the word 'Restaurants' (I got the Montreal stuff fixed)... Any idea ? Thanks !

Comment: By the way in the data all the elements are in this format: `{'business_id': '1SWheh84yJXfytovILXOAQ',
  'name': 'Arizona Biltmore Golf Club',
  'address': '2818 E Camino Acequia Drive',
  'city': 'Phoenix',
  'state': 'AZ',
  'postal_code': '85016',
  'latitude': 33.5221425,
  'longitude': -112.0184807,
  'stars': 3.0,
  'review_count': 5,
  'is_open': 0,
  'attributes': {'GoodForKids': 'False'},
  'categories': 'Golf, Active Life',
  'hours': None}`    Basically a list of dictionaries like that and I am sure the keys I am using are correct.

Comment: You might have entries missing either `postal_code` or `categories`. You can iterate over the data as such `for entry in data` and then check if the postal_code and categories exists on the entry before doing your comparison.

Comment: @AbassSesay                                                                         
 There doesn't seem to be any problem with postal_code or categories, I can run the following for categories and not get any error: `counter =0
for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i]['categories'] == 'Restaurants':
        counter += 1
print(compteur) `                                                                   And it would return 0 and for postal code as well it does already work. The problem is each element on the 'categories' have multiple character and I just want 'restaurants'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code provided, it seems that the error is most likely coming from the if condition. Specifically, it is most likely coming from the statement `'Restaurants' in data[i]['categories']`. Under the hood, Python is trying to iterate through `data[i]['categories']` to see if 'Restaurants' is in it. If `data[i]['categories']` is `None`, that would cause this error.

This may be caused by the JSON string not being formatted the way you expected. Perhaps, if no categories were listed in the 'Categories' field, a `null` was put instead of an empty list. To check for this in your code, you can try the following:

```
compteur3 = 0
for i in range(len(data)):
    is_inmontreal = data[i]['postal_code'][0:3] in postal_mtl
    is_restaurant = data[i]['categories'] and 'Restaurants' in data[i]['categories']
    if is_inmontreal and is_restaurant:
        compteur3 += 1
print(compteur3)
```

Above, I simply split the condition into two parts. Functionally, this would be the same as having the conditions in one line, it just makes it slightly clearer. However, I also added a check in `is_restaurant` to see if `data[i]['categories']` has a positive truth value. In effect, this will check if the value is not `None` and it is not an empty list. If you really want to be explicit, you can also do

```
is_restaurant = data[i]['categories'] is not None and 'Restaurants' in data[i]['categories']
```

Depending on how dirty the data is, you may need to go a little further than this and use exception handling. However, the above is just speculation as I do not know what the data looks like.